# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [15996, 8]

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have loaded the dataset using pandas and printed the first 5 rows

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'filename')print(df.shape)
print(df.shape)
```

prints out the number of rows and columns in the dataset

> (15997, 8)

```
print(df.head(5))
```

[Just to show what the results look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqyzK.png)

Then if if I split the dataset

```
X = df.iloc[1:].values
y = df.iloc[0].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.4,random_state=42, stratify=y)
```

I get this error

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [15996, 8]

I need the X value to exclude the first row from the dataset and y value to only include the first row

Answer (score 2):

for **df.iloc** first index works as key, so you are splitting on rows. Second index is for columns. Try this:-

```
X = data.iloc[:,1:]
Y = data.iloc[:,0]
```

Comment: y is supposed to be the first row of the dataset not column and X is the whole dataset excluding the first row. The code above takes out the first column from the dataset for X and y takes the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
X = data.iloc[:,1:]
y = data.iloc[:,0]
```

Since your dataframe has two dimensions, you have to slice in both dimensions in order to create a subframe.